# How set a JSON value based on a second value and also number of occurrences of a third value

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

Initial `files.json` document state:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": "unknown"
  },
  {
    "filename": "b",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": "unknown"
  },
  {
    "filename": "c",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": "unknown"
  },
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": "unknown"
  }
]
```

When a "filename" value occurs just once in the document, the "type" value will only depend on the "dir" value: `"dir" == "foo" --> "type" = 0` and `"dir" == "bar" --> "type" = 1`

When a "filename" value exists both in "foo" and also in "bar" directories, "type" must have value == 2, like here:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": "2"
  },
  {
    "filename": "b",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": "0"
  },
  {
    "filename": "c",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": "1"
  },
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": "2"
  }
]
```

The "dir" value will always be limited to the two possible alternatives of "foo" or "bar" values and will never be null.
Even the "filename" value will be ever set, and since these are really files, can not be present in document more than twice at most.

I want to do this with jq 1.5 (16 Aug 2015 stable release) running from a Bash script in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that is similar to that by @CharlesDuffy but a little shorter and more "jq-ish":

```
(reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x.filename] += [$x.dir])
 | map_values(unique)) as $dirs
| map( $dirs[.filename] as $d
       | .type |= if $d|length > 1 then 2
                  elif $d[0] == "bar" then 1
                  else 0
                  end)
```

### Using `catalog/3`

With the help of the generic helper function `catalog/3`:

```
def catalog(s; keyp; valuep):
   reduce s as $x ({}; (.[$x|keyp|tostring]) += [$x|valuep]);
```

the solution becomes a bit more readable:

```
(catalog(.[]; .filename; .dir) | map_values(unique)) as $dirs
| map( $dirs[.filename] as $d
       | .type |= if $d|length > 1 then 2
                  elif $d[0] == "bar" then 1
                  else 0
                  end)
```

Comment: This seems to me to be the perfect solution, one that allows itself to be read and understood easily and does its job well.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `group_by`.  In the following, `group_by` is used naively, so the ordering of the final results in the array is determined by .filename; if that is unsatisfactory, one could use the same technique to construct a lookup table, which would then be used against the original array.

```
[group_by(.filename)[]
 | (map(.dir) 
    | unique
    | if length>1 then length
      elif .[0] == "foo" then 0
      elif .[0] == "bar" then 1
      else .[0]          # just in case
      end) as $type
    | (.[] + {type: $type} ) ]
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": 2
  },
  {
    "filename": "a",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": 2
  },
  {
    "filename": "b",
    "dir": "foo",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "filename": "c",
    "dir": "bar",
    "type": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: @peak: In fact, the document has a prior sorting not based on "filename" that I like to be able to keep although this filter it would have gone still well. But there is your second solution, as beautiful as a poem.... How much I still have to learn!

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '
([.[] | { (.filename): {(.dir): true} }] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)) as $seen |
map(
  if $seen[.filename]["foo"] and $seen[.filename]["bar"] then
    .type = 2
  elif $seen[.filename]["bar"] then
    .type = 1
  else
    .type = 0
  end
)
'
```

---

If it helps in understanding how this works -- `$seen` has a value that looks like the following:

```
{
  "a": {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": true
  },
  "b": {
    "foo": true
  },
  "c": {
    "bar": true
  }
}
```

...thus giving us easy access to look at which dir entries a given filename has ever been seen with.

Comment: Thank you @Charles, it's a good solution! And you inspired the second proposal from peak which became my favourite because it seems more 'robust' to me; for example, as is, doesn't depend on the current "type" value, differently from here (although, this can easily be obtained here too, I believe)..

Comment: If you didn't *want* to change only things with a current `type` of `unknown`, that's just a matter of removing that `if`.